# how to code to connect iPhone Message Access Profile

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I want to use bluetooth 4.0 to access iOS devices use message access profile. I can create socket with iOS device use RFCOMM and MAS UUID, but when I use this request byte to connect, I got a forbidden response(195). Can anybody can provide a sample code.

Comment: FYI... MAP is not over corebluetooth or BT LE, its on classic bluetooth.

Comment: BT LE is part of Bluetooth 4.0.That's not key.I can use classic bluetooth to communicate with iOS Device.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using that isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Your code might not be the problem here.

There is a forbidden response because of you did not enable MAP on your iOS device for the device you want to connect as Messaging Server.

You need to enable it for each device in your paired device list.

(Settings -> Bluetooth -> ringed 'i' of your device ->Show Messages)

Apple set default off. I guess they don't really want that anybody uses MAP with iPhones.